# How to call componentResized method just once (when user stops holding mouse button)?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to implement ComponentListener in my swing app in way that each time my main JFrame window will be resized listener should respond to that action.
The problem is that in:

```
window.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(window.getWidth());
            System.out.println(window.getHeight());
        }
```

I clearly see that method is called each time window is resized just by just small difference. I want to call componentResized method just once, at the end of resizing.

How can I do that? Do i need muse listener to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I clearly see that method is called each time window is resized just by just small difference

Yes, but why is that a problem. All GUI's tend to resize dynamically. Why don't you want to do this. If the know the reason maybe we can suggest a better approach.

Anyway, I think you might be looking for:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setDynamicLayout( false );
```

Comment: Thanks. I just thought that at some point resizing all images and stuff in my app due to dynamics changes of windows size might be unnecessary power consumption.

Comment: @MaciejF, don't assume. Try it and see how it works. The dynamic painting of image is very fast and the user usually expects resizing immediately not when you release the mouse.